# RestSharp Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, restsharp

I am trying to use RestSharp in a console application, to connect to an api and get a cookie, but in the response, i keep getting "Unable to connect to remote server".

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate");
        client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("login", "????", "password", "????");

        var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I basically expect RestSharp to call the following:

```
finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=???&password=???
```

This works for me in postman, but not in restsharp.
I have tested with http://ip.jsontest.com, to test if i can connect to any outside apis, this works and get my ip back.
Any ideas???

Comment: what version of RestSharp are you using?

Comment: _"resource"_ not incuded at expected url, why you use it at `new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET)`? You can check your request via fiddler.

Comment: @Noel version 106.1.0

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I followed the documentation on https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Authenticators, if you look at the bottom

Comment: and whats the error code? include it in your answer please. anyways i think you need to remove _resourse_ from your `RestRequest` to make it work

Comment: @parapark, read documentation one more time: "The URL generated for this request would be http://example.com/ **resource** ?username=foo&password=bar"

Comment: In the response object I keep getting "Unable to connect to the remote server". That is my error

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov you are right..

Comment: there is an error code to further explain the error... anyways the answer below seems very correct to me. try that

Comment: Don't change the question into a new and totally different question. If this question has been answered (which it has) then as a new one about the new error.

Comment: @Equalsk it is really not a totally different question, the error I get is the same. I will ask the question again, but it does seem silly.

Comment: It's your question, you can change it as you see fit, but if it changes so much that it invalidates all answers given then you're doing something wrong... Also, the error you're getting is now not related to this code, it's a networking issue which only you can solve. I'll leave it in your hands.

Comment: @Equalsk i get what you are saying.
I do not believe it to be a networking issue.
I can access finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=???&password=???
from multiple browswer, from postman, but not through restsharp.
That cannot be networking issue, please test finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=???&password=??? in your own browser.

Comment: No, I don't mean your network is broken, I mean it's blocking your application. It's most likely that a firewall is blocking your application, or you have a proxy server. Only you can know the details of either of these things so it would be up to you to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/");
client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("login", "????", "password", "????");

var request = new RestRequest("Authenticate", Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

You didn't look at the documentation you linked to properly. In its example the URL is:

```
http://example.com/resource?username=foo&password=bar
```

Pay attention to where `resource` appears. Your URL shows `Authenticate` in that place instead.

Comment: I changed it, and of course, the changes makes sense, but i still get the following message in the reponse object
"Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: That's a different issue and would not be related to this code. I'm unable to connect to the address you provided, I get a timeout. Are you absolutely sure it's valid? Additionally your application my be blocked by other things such as your firewall but that's something only you can troubleshoot.

Comment: if you try it through postman, it works as intended.
And if i try another url in restsharp it works too...

Comment: I'm well aware of Postman. That URL does not work for me in at all in any program, I always get a timeout. I'm sure you're doing something wrong, but there's no way to guess what that is as it's not related to the code you've shown (apart from the address seemingly being invalid).

Comment: try and change the authentication to this `
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + USERNAME_PASSWORD_HERE");`

Comment: @Equalsk this is the link i am trying to create, if you type this in your browser, you get a timeout?
    finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=???&password=???

Comment: @Noel but i am not trying to send them as headers, but url as params...

Comment: ok but im pretty sure your request has at least some kind of basic authentication... (most probably some kind of base 64 encoded string) ... check your postman headers... I'm insisting because i had the same issue a few days ago

Comment: I get that, but i asure it does not, if i called the site through my browser with the correct login and pass as url segments or params, i get a status code 200...

Comment: ok I understand. `var request = new RestRequest("Authenticate?username={username}&password={password}", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("username", "1234", ParameterType.UrlSegment); request.AddParameter("password", "1234", ParameterType.UrlSegment);   ` Try this as a last resort.. it must work. Im not sure if that is the way it is supposed to add both parameters thought.

Comment: @Noel i appreciate the effort, but it did not work, i still get "Unable to connect to remote server". Currently, i am thinking that it does "dot" in the Api.mvc might be the culprit

Comment: I'm out of ideas for now.. as long as your browser opens the same url it doesn't make sense for that to be the error.. anyways if i come across to a new idea i will comment again or post an answer.